# Problem with saving FileReader result to array

Tags: angular, typescript

```
public imagePath;
public imagePaths: Book[] = [];
imageURL: string;

createImageFromBlob(image: Blob): void {
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.addEventListener("load", () => {
       this.imageURL = reader.result as string;
       this.imagePaths.push(new Book('Book1', this.imageURL));
       console.log(this.imageURL); // OK
       console.log(this.imagePaths[0].image ); // wrong output
      });
      reader.readAsDataURL(image);
}
```

I have method that converts an image in BLOB format into string.

```
reader.result as string
```

returns correct string. But when I try to save imageURL in Book object it is not saved correctly because the line

```
   console.log('test2' + this.imagePaths[0].image );
```

gives me message 'undefined'.

My Book class:

```
export class Book{
    name: string;
    image: string;

    constructor(name: string,image: string) {}
}
```

Comment: How does your Book class look like?

Comment: export class Book{
    name: string;
    image: string;

    constructor(name: string,image: string) {}
}

Comment: well do you set your properties in the constructor? because in that piece it doesn't look like this